# MongoDB: How can I add an Object into an array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, mongodb

I have been working with MongoDB and I have a requirement that I don't know how to solve with this technology.

Maybe with an example it will be better understood.

I have two interfaces like this:

```
export interface Alumn{
    id: string;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}
```

```
export interface Class{
   id: string;
   room: number;
   alumns: [
     member: Alumn; (Referencing the other interface)
 ]
}
```

And what I want to do is add that Alumn object into the array that belongs to the Class interface with MongoDB.

```
   id: string;
   room: number;
   alumns: [
     member: {id, name, age}
 ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some error doing this?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to do it with Mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$push`

```
db.collection.update(
{
  _id: 1
},
{
  $push: {
    albums: {
      $each: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "a",
          "age": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

**Example：[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_1G-J-bVZ96)**